# How to saving class cart array values in MySQL in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, arrays

How to saving these array values in MySQL in CodeIgniter and Array is

```
Array
(
[c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [qty] => 1
        [price] => 4000
        [name] => camera
        [rowid] => c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b
        [subtotal] => 4000
    )

[e4da3b7fbbce2345d7772b0674a318d5] => Array
    (
        [id] => 5
        [qty] => 1
        [price] => 5000
        [name] => camera
        [rowid] => e4da3b7fbbce2345d7772b0674a318d5
        [subtotal] => 5000
    )
)

echo '<pre>';
$cont['uhu']=$this->cart->contents();
print_r($cont['uhu']);
```

Comment: why both [id] is same?

Answer (score 0):

According to [docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#inserting-data), saving values to mysql (DB) use batch insert function

```
$this->db->insert_batch('Tablename', $YourDataArray);
```

and array index (key) should match with database columns